# What is most economical outside of eurozone: debitcard (maestro) or creditcard (mastercard)?

Tags: payment-cards, eurozone

I am EU citizen travelling to Switzerland soon. Would it make most sense to make my payments with maestro or with my mastercard ? How about cash withdrawals ?

Comment: economical in what sense? the price you pay at the POS will likely be the same either way.

Comment: You absolutely *don’t* want to withdraw cash or make a cash equivalent transaction, such as buying foreign currency or money orders, on a credit card. Typically you’ll be charged a cash advance fee, interest is always charged from the date you make the withdrawal or equivalent transaction, and it will also incur a different interest rate. If you make a non-Euro transaction on your credit (or debit) card while you’re in Switzerland, you'll be charged a transaction fee too.

Comment: It depends on your bank (and the exact foreign transaction fee structures you agreed with them).

Comment: Banking fees has in many EU countries during the last years increased so much, that it is often cheapest to bring cash and change to local currency in the country you are visiting. That is what I am usually doing.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Uh? I would think quite the opposite… EU rules say that the cost must be the same for domestic and for intra-EU transactions in EUR. OP’s case is slightly different (since it involves Switzerland), but competition has drawn fees down quite a bit I believe.

Comment: Would also favour Maestro over Mastercard.

Comment: @jcaron I meant when using my in a euro-country issued card in a non-euro country. The banks are allowed to charge for the currency exchange. Paying with credit card, there is no fixed fee, but my bank hides a usually 3-5% fee (Visa's already poor exchange rate + 1.85%) in the currency exchange rate. Paying with debit card in an EEA/non-euro country, my bank adds 2% to the ECB reference exchange rate and an additional '1,75% but at least 1,50€' fee for payments. If I pay a 1€ bottle of water, the real charge is 2,52€.

Answer (score 3):

> I am EU citizen travelling to Switzerland soon. Would it make most sense to make my payments with maestro or with my mastercard ?

This depends a lot on the terms and conditions of your mastercard. I generally pay with credit card since a) I get 2.66% cash back and b) there is no foreign transaction fee. If your mastercard charges fees and/or doesn't offer benefits, use the debit card instead.

> How about cash withdrawals ?

NEVER EVER use a credit card to get cash unless you have absolutely no other choice.  The interest, fees and malicious payoff rules are banking at its worst. Use your maestro debit card for getting cash. This can still incur a fair bit of fees, so using good credit card is the best choice. Try to minimize your cash needs.